# Download audio from soundcloud for game creator

Tags: soundcloud

Hi I was wanting to use "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/soundcloudIdHere/download" in a game and I don't want run into any legal issues. I want the user to be able to enter a soundcloud url, the game would convert this into an id and check if it downloadable, then the user can publish the level on my servers with the soundcloud id so others can download the level and music.

Answer (score 0):

You should read SoundCloud's Terms of Service, especially the 2nd paragraph of the Grant of License. It sounds possible if it's not a commercial game.

https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use#grant-of-license

Comment: I was wanting to sell my game( for money via one time fee, ads, and/or in app purchases)  , so would I be making a commercial game?

Comment: Sounds like it. You should read the ToS and probably consult an attorney.